# IOS Game center Group of Games - Achievements not working in one app only

Tags: objective-c, ios7, game-center

I have 2 apps - a free and a paid app in game center group at moment.

first i created paid app in itunes and then creates all achievement identifier with `com.xxx.yyy` (example)

Then i created free app in itunes and create group of games and achievement's identifier get updated to `grp.com.xxx.yyy`
This is ok and itunes showing free and paid app in group with identifiers `grp.com.xxx.yyy`.

Now when i tried to report or load achievement with `grp.com.xxx.yyy` from **free app**, all thing is working fine. All reported achievements are reflecting within game center for free app in all ios version

Now when i am reporting same achievement with paid app, game center shows reported successfully and also get reflecting in ios 5 and ios 6. but it is not reflecting in ios7 game center. When i do some logs then i found that **paid app** is loading `com.xxx.yyy` (old achievements) from game center though i reported `grp.com.xxx.yyy` and showing reported successfully in paid app. Even though i am getting wrong reported identifiers, it is reflecting with ios 5 and ios 6 achievements listing but in ios 7 it is not reflecting. And every time shows banner in ios7 with same achievement because when i am checking that achievement is already reported or not that time i am getting old identifiers from game center that's why paid app try to register same achievements again. This thing is happening with all ios version but ios 7 only shows banner every time in paid app live version. And in sandbox that banner was missing at all.

Have any one knows abut this issue then help me. is it related to game center multiplayer compatibility or not?

Some one have also this kind of issue, you can see in [this forum](http://forums.gamesalad.com/discussion/50145/does-gs-gamecenter-behaviour-have-acces-to-grouped-leaderboards)
I have also wrote code here for more reference,

```
 [GKAchievement loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *achievements, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error == nil)
         {
             for (GKAchievement* achievement in achievements)
                 if (achievement.percentComplete == 100) 
                 {
                     [achievementsarray addObject: achievement.identifier];

// Getting com.xxx.yyy(wrong/old) for paid app and grp.com.xxx.yyy (right) for free app here

                 }
         }

         NSMutableArray *reporttogc = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
         for (int i = 0; i< [[[results valueForKey:@"Achivement"] valueForKey:@"identifier"] count]; i++) {
             GKAchievement *achievement = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[results valueForKey:@"Achivement"]objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"identifier"]]]; 

// For free and paid both app have passing same identifier here - grp.com.xxx.yyy

             achievement.percentComplete = [[[[results valueForKey:@"Achivement"]objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"value"]doubleValue];
             achievement.showsCompletionBanner = YES;

             if (![achievementsarray containsObject:achievement.identifier]) 
             {

                 [reporttogc addObject:achievement];

             }

             [achievement release];
         }

         if([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]intValue]==5)
         {
             for (GKAchievement* achievement in reporttogc)
             {

                 [self reportAchievementIdentifier:achievement.identifier percentComplete:achievement.percentComplete];

             }

         }
         else if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]intValue]>=6)
         {
             [GKAchievement reportAchievements:reporttogc withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
              {

                  if (error != nil)  
                  {

                      NSLog(@"Error in reporting achievements: %@", error);

                  }
                  else
                  {

                      NSLog(@"sucess:achievements");

                  }
              }];
         } 
     }];
```

Comment: I have just moved my achievements to groups and i'm experiencing the same behaviour. Have you solved your issues in the meantime?

Comment: @SimonMeyer there is no way to resolve it out. I talked to apple around 3 months and they didn't solve my problem. Finally i create new app with that group and upload it to iTunes.